# Application idle Timer disable not working

Tags: ios, iphone, video, ios8

Application idle timer disable is not working properly after record video from the application. I put below code in my application did finish launching. please suggest me if any one have idea to handle idle timer.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

Comment: Please post code about how do you play video

Comment: @NikitaZernov I record video using UIImagePickerController. not play video.

Answer (score 0):

In the past there have been some bugs in iOS, in which it forgets that you have set `idleTimerDisabled`, for example after you have used the `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture. I am not sure whether Apple has fixed those bugs completely yet.

A work-around is to set it more often, for example in the `viewWillAppear` of your main view.